# I need to convert the date column for which the data type is object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a object column in pandas dataframe with all the dates in it such as `[4/12/1936, ??-??-1965, ??-01,1999]` and I need to convert it to date time datatype to extract year and date from it.

How to deal with it as it has some missing values?(Python)

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: there are `??` in data?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: My data frame col is such that few of the rows have missing values for month and date as as [4/12/1936, ??-??-1944] . Where the ? is missing value . Even i am sure how to proceed with this, as i have been asked to convert the data

Comment: So there are 3 columns?

Comment: there is only one col with all these values

Comment: what is your definition how you want to handle the missing day/month year? also, your example suggests different separators might appear, such as `/`, `-` or `,` - is that correct?

Comment: No there are no separators, in the example each date belong to same col, different rows. All i need is to handle the missing values that is "?"  in my current data set